# Many-to-Many relationship Database in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-7.1

I have a simple task:
To build notepad with hashtags.
So user will be able to add a note and to add a list of #hashtags to it.

Basically I will have 2 objects:
`Note`
`Hashtag`

I want to be able to access all:
Assigned hashtags to a specific note by `note.RelatedHashtags`
Assigned notes to a specific hashtag by `hashtag.RelatedNotes`

It sounds like many-to-many, but I can't find any code example that I can learn from for Windows Phone. Also it sounds like I need to add a third object (table) to keep the data in the needed structure, but than how the mappings should be configured?

The most informative link I found so far:
http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/windows-phone-mango-local-database-sql-ce--association-attribute

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple - to create a third table and relate it to both `Notes` and `Hashtags` tables.
I found some very useful code example [here](http://dotnetspeak.com/2011/07/sql-ce-on-windows-phone-7-1-mango).

P.S.: Don't forget to check [Local database best practices for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286406%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)